# Trim trailing space in jasypt EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jasypt

We are using Spring along with jasypt `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to read the application.properties file.

The problem sometimes happen if some of the properties value contain white-spaces in the end, on reading the value using the `@Value(${})` tag, we get the trailing space also in the end which creates problems.

Now the class `EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is final so can't be extended and I searched a lot to figure out if any way to get the properties after trimming of the white-spaces around the string value.

Can anybody suggest how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the answer to my problem with help from "bellabax"
I overrid the Properties persister and implemented my own method

```
propertyConfigurator.setPropertiesPersister(new MyDefaultPropertiesPersister());
```

---

```
    @Override
    public void load(Properties props, InputStream is) throws IOException {

    props.load(is);
    for (Entry<Object, Object> property : props.entrySet()) {
        property.setValue(property.getValue().toString().trim());
    }
}
```

Now my properties are trimmed of trailing space
I hope this helps some one.

Comment: Good to know! This was my first choice,but I discard them because I think PropertiesPersister loads properties in ENC(xxx) form and not as decrypted value (and you can't trim() value as ENC(...),doesn't make sense). My advice was simply deduced reading javadoc,I didn't try it because I never used mjasypt

Comment: Thanks for the effort. My requirement was just to trim whatever value is on the right side of = whether its surrounded by ENC or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer with custom StringEncryptor passed in constructor. In this CustomStringEncryptor.decrypt() do your trim(). (In this case you don't know which is the property you are decrypting)

You can bypass final with delegation:

```
class CustomStringEncryptor implements StringEncryptor{
  private StringEncryptor delegate;

  public CustomStringEncryptor(StandardPBEStringEncryptor delegate){
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  String decrypt(String encryptedMessage){
    String message = this.delegate.decrypt(encryptedMessage);
    if(null != message) message = message.trim();
    return message;
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, we are already using StandardPBEStringEncryptor as the String encryptor and this class is again a final class. I tried putting a debug point in the decrypt method of this class, it never ends up there.
Most of the properties are simple text not surrounded by ENC()